# SQL query to transpose rows to columns in MS Access table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have the following MS Access 2010 table (No,F1 F2 are the headers):

```
No F1  F2
1  a1  b1
2  a1  b2
3  a3  b3
4  a4  b4
5  a5  b5
6  a6  b6
```

I need an SQL query to perform a transpose columns to rows operation in order to obtain the following output:

```
1   2    3   4   5   6
a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6
b1  b2  b3  b4  b5  b6
```

Thank you, 
M.R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Access doesn't have SQL function like `UNPIVOT` in MS SQL, so for transposing you can use UNION SQL with number of subqueries equal number of columns in source table, or you can use VBA code like this:

```
Dim f As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM TableSrc")
    .MoveLast
    .MoveFirst
    f = .GetRows(.RecordCount)
End With

With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM TableDest")
    For i = 0 To UBound(f)
        .AddNew
        For j = 0 To UBound(f, 2)
            .Fields(j) = f(i, j)
        Next j
        .Update
    Next i
End With
```

Function `GetRows` loads whole table into two dimensional array, then just unload this array to destination table

Comment: Thank you for the code, no doubt it will work, however... MS Access has TRANSPOSE and PIVOT functions,maybe would be possible to use this approach in order to get the desired output with just one query?

Comment: You mean `TRANSFORM` and `PIVOT`? That's a little bit different thing, I'm afraid it won't help with transposing because you need to use aggregate functions for values

Comment: And as I said, you can transpose using one `UNION` query, but this solution is not flexible, column names will be fixed.